# Insane tick lag in Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods, performance

I'm running Minecraft on the following machine:
Windows 8 x64, 8 GB RAM (4 allocated for Minecraft), i5-2500K @ 4.5Ghz, AMD Radeon R9 290.

I've got about 70 mods including Buildcraft, Thermal Expansion, and some other common technology mods. I haven't had this issue in earlier versions of Minecraft. As for Forge, I'm using 1226 (one of the latest builds).

Now when I play independent of which map and with or without mods, the game is running very patchy. I get an average framerate of 30 with Mods and ~60 without Mods. Though I have at least 30 FPS, the game stutters. This is caused by random lag spikes which occur all 1-10 ticks. Here a screenshot of my lag-o-meter and the profiler:
[image: My machine]

Like you can see, a lot of irregular spikes and very high tick times. Moreover, in Debug view I get every now and again a message that something is taking too long and "root" or "root.tick" or "root.render" or others took approx. 110ms.

Now as I'm curious I tested the same on a machine that is set up exactly the same but running on an Intel Celeron (2-cores) @ 3.2 GHz and with an Nvidia Geforce GTX 560 Ti.

The game runs perfectly smooth with all mods. The ticks are short and equal and I get an average of 60 FPS with Mods and highest viewing distance. Here take a look, the same world just on the other machine:
[image: Testing machine]

You clearly see the difference and the profiler shows that the ratio between Tick and Rendering is exactly the opposite to mine here.

Now does anybody know why this happens to be? I really don't get it. I've tried out all. Various Java parameters people suggested all over the web, tried Java 8, tried different Java versions, played around with the allocated RAM but nothing helped... It just doesn't run smooth and playing so is horrible.

I recently had a problem that randomly the menu's lagged and audio glitches (CPU frozen) occurred in Thief. Since that time I went down with the clock, though a lot of intense burn-ins said it would be stable. Now, these glitches didn't appear anymore, but I can't believe that Minecraft stresses the CPU so much that it's getting unstable... Moreover, I tried Terasology (maximum graphics settings) when the clock was still higher. It ran with a smooth 60 FPS and without issues. I tried it again a few days later and then it lagged the same as Minecraft did, just that Terasology sooner or later crashed with a "somewhat Delay" exception. I guess the same issue — unstable ticks.

All other games work just fine, without any troubles. It looks like it's just with Java games...

Comment: this game is written in java, you overload it with mods and you expect it to run smoothly?

Comment: What OS is running on the celeron? Possibly windows 8 bloat causing this? Can you try linux?

Comment: I know @PhilippSander, but on the weaker system it runs with smooth and stable 60 FPS. It's my more powerful system which can't get it running smoothly! So in this case, Java isn't the problem. Both run, as mentioned, Windows 8.1 x64. And nope, I won't reinstall my OS nor install a second one. Moreover I don't believe it's the OS - it ran perfectly good back in January when I played last (on 8.1, too). And the weaker system runs 8.1, too, but without any lags. Must be something else :-/

Comment: i't could be the graphics libary they used. NVIDIA is more supported than Raedon cards

Comment: But then it must be the rendering which takes too long, not the updates, mustn't it? The framerate drops because the graphics card don't get instructions fast enough.

Comment: Try in fullscreen, it helped me (the frequency of the GPU wasn't going up as needed).

Comment: You may notice that the screen resolution is way smaller on the second screenshot.

Comment: Sure, the other monitor was just 19", but it's all about the CPU. Both lag-o-meters show a nearly same height of green, which means the ratio of GPU time is about equal. But the white lines, the ticks, are a lot higher on my machine. I don't believe it's the graphics card. This makes no sense :-/ I'll try fullscreen, but I'm sure this won't change much :-/

Comment: "My minecraft with mods installed is running too slowly" is clearly tech support for modded minecraft and therefore off-topic.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because tech support for modded Minecraft is off-topic here.

Comment: @Gigazelle As far as I understand it, that close reason is meant for crash support of modded minecraft rather than all tech support, see [here](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13489/arqade-community-check-in-2019-a-call-for-input/13506#comment42533_13506) for reference. (there are some hidden comments that are important, too, and this only uses Robotnik as a reference, so I may still be wrong, or misunderstand it even after asking). Note that this reference is about the comments rather than the answer itself

Comment: In context of this question, there are 70+ mods installed, and there is no issue in vanilla Minecraft. The meta thread discussing modded Minecraft support (https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10390/minecraft-crash-questions-should-be-made-off-topic-yes-no) includes not only crashes, but issues as well. While not all questions for modded Minecraft are off-topic, this one in my opinion most definitely is.

Answer (score 4):

Lag spikes are caused by three possible things:

**Just remember, there are multiple ways to fix these problems, and multiple things that may be causing these problems.**

- Too many packets!
  *Minecraft can only handle ever-so-many chunk updates in a single setting; tick. Because it cannot finish all the updates in that single 1/20 of a second, it freezes the world until it is able to complete the processing for that tick.*

You can improve the amount of work it can do by getting a better CPU; processor (or giving Minecraft more priority over other tasks). RAM only allows you to have a greater workload; not go through that workload quicker.

Because the server and the client (if you're playing single-player) are both linked, your game freezes when it is unable to finish all the work (updating of data; the world OR rendering the world*) within the time frame of a tick (1/20 of a second).

<sup>*</sup> Note: More than 20FPS means more than one frame created in a single tick.

- Wait. I'm still writing...
  *When you have a Minecraft world, the game constantly saves the world to the disk (unless you've increase the interval that it does this) every 3 seconds. However, if the server is unable to write to the disk, it freezes the server to ensure that the data state that needs to be saved does not get changed. If it can save it in one go, of course - Everything will continue as per normal.*

Pretty much, the only way to prevent this is to stop all, or at least the processes/tasks/programs hogging I/O capabilities in background that is reading to the disk, or get a better hard disk drive.
(i.e. Steam updating files, copy-pasting commands, saving school/home/work-work etc.; anything involving reading and writing to a disk)

- Inefficient coding, AKA. Bugs
  *Very unlikely, if not - Not even applicable here, but there may be bad coding in the <s>game and</s> mods' codes that make it leak memory or constantly remember new things in memory without clearing out redundant values.*

Though some of the large mods are known to do this, and most of them by now have already fixed most (if not, all) problems causing spikes in memory usage. The only way is to solve this is to fix the coding yourself, if the source code is released.

---

If all else fails (without uninstalling/modifying the mods you have):

1. Revert to the low-resolution textures
2. Lower your audio and video settings
3. Close ALL other tasks other than Minecraft.

### because it most likely because your computer can't handle it.

I could continue with how Java is an emulated system (virtual OS inside a running OS) and how emulators run slower because it needs to emulate a system architecture that is completely different to those of a PC/whatever device, but that's not the point.

Minecraft runs on Java, which requires a virtual machine to be emulated inside your computer. Because of that - Emulation takes more memory and CPU processing power than it usually needs (if you were to run it on the native OS).
The reason other games worked is because they are native to Windows; don't need to go through 5 other steps before a value can be changed or something can be outputted.

Comment: On top of the "Wait. I'm still writing..." you could do /save-off to disable world saving and check for a tick lag improvement. Of course this means more game held in memory instead of writing to disk. (Manually save with /save-all and enable with /save-on)

Comment: Well, thanks, but none of these advices does apply to this situation. Please read my inital question carefully. I've written that the second machine is a lot less powerful in CPU as well as GPU. My system is way faster and I already enabled all Multi-Core stuff in Optifine. As to your suggestion of I/O: Both systems have their Minecraft files stored on a SSD, so writing can surely not cause any lags. Moreover I've set the save interval to 1 minute (or 3, not sure yet). It must be either a program which interferes or the CPU. Maybe Java has a problem with my overclocked CPU ...?!

Comment: `/save-off` is only for the dedicated server programs, not client-servers. (The server that runs when you play Single Player, or open to LAN)

Comment: With the mod "Optifine" you can change the autosave time from (correct my if i'm not right) 2 seconds to 30 minutes (and off).

Comment: @nelson2tm, he is talking about his single player world; client-server (that has mods on it), not a dedicated server. Also, the [BetterLAN Mod](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/mapping-and-modding/minecraft-mods/1284959-1-6-2-forge-betterlan-v1-0-6); one that uses Bukkit as a client-server only supports up to 1.6.2; he is using 1.7.10.

Comment: @aytimothy Whoops! i did mean optifine! :$ (edited)

Comment: And yes, you can change the autosave time... But that's just simply delaying the time between each lag spike (autosave)

Comment: This is a very interesting problem, and one shared by many modded minecraft players. Sadly, I believe the solution to your problem is to use what you've proven to yourself works; the "slower" computer. There are lots of variables in play when trying to tweak out java performance. More variables = more difficult to predict, troubleshoot or fix. There is some very good feedback coming here, but the bolded large text in this answer by @aytimothy is correct. Whatever is causing it, your symptoms indicate that for whatever reason your computer isn't "handling it".

Comment: My computer handles Crysis 3 on max. without the slightest problem, running smooth 60 FPS. Terasology, which is ten times more intense in case of graphics than Minecraft + Shaders MOD + SEUS Ultra and runs with smooth 60 FPS. Every game runs just fine and I just tried uninstalling and stopping a lot of applications. Nothing worked. I made a clean re-install of Minecraft and it still doesn't work. Even the Vanilla Minecraft shows "Warning: Clientside chunk ticking took 169 ms". And lags all the time. Saving is surely not the problem because, as said, it's running on an SSD ;) Must be sth. else.

Comment: Correction: I meant Minecraft with just Forge. And here comes my conclusion. I just ran Vanilla without Forge. Permanent 70 FPS, no lags, no warnings. It MUST BE Forge which causes these issues, but why the hell does it. I don't get what could be programmatically the problem (I'm a programmer) that Forge runs on the one computer fine and here it doesn't ...

Comment: When you said `Warning: Clientside chunk ticking took 169 ms`, it means that your game took too long to process a chunk's worth of update in a single tick. You either have to upgrade your computer or get a better one.

Comment: @SharpShade Your problem is isolated to Forge? That is really very interesting. I wonder if somehow your java configuration is getting in the way. There may be a tipping point somehow being exceeded with the addition of Forge, or there is a bug between your java environment and something Forge is trying to do. If you want a tip of something to try - create a new partition (or virtual machine) and get a fresh install of java and see if that runs poorly. If a fresh install (of the OS and java) runs well, then there is something peculiar about your java environment. If not then that's not it.

Comment: @aytimothy Kudos for a super-well worded answer and responsiveness. Good work!

Comment: I know how Java works and I know that eventually this is a lot slower than native games written in C++. And I appreciate your answer, but you repeat the same all over again. I mentioned that the current system is a lot faster than the other I tested MC on, but still it runs on the weaker one without any problem and here it lags like hell. It just can't be the hardware. This is clearly excluded. Moreover vanilla runs just fine and fast. It's forge which causes these problems. At least the issues show up with a Forge MC version (without any mods, though)...

Comment: @SharpShade, did you figure it out? Minecraft now comes with its own JRE to avoid problems like this, so it may have solved the problem now.

Comment: Been a while since I last checked for that. Moreover it IS definetly Forge that is causing these issues. Don't know if it's the JRE with Forge on top that is causing it, though. I will check it out and report it here then ;)

Comment: @Synetech You're a bit *too* late for the party. (If you know what I'm trying to say)

Comment: Some of us are still having problems...

Answer (score 0):

Have you recently overclocked your monitor? If so, change the refresh rate back to it's original state. It worked for me so if this is your scenario then it will work for you.

Comment: No, I don't see any reason for overclocking my terribly old monitor...